# Xtabs with character values

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm fitting some tables with `xtabs`, to be able to better turn them into tables in markdown with the `kable` function. It has worked out great for me so far, but once I wanted to create a table that contained character values, I was met with the following message:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

The dataframe I want to convert looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   CandidateType [2]
  CandidateType       Step   Amount  Pct
        <fctr>       <chr>   <dbl>  <chr>
1      External Applications 12567 100.0%
2      Internal Applications  1174 100.0%
3      External Interview     1204   9.6%
4      Internal Interview      541  46.1%
5      External Hiring         157   1.2%
6      Internal Hiring         198  16.9%
```

When I do the following, it all works out totally fine, since the Amount-variable is a numeric class variable:

```
inExQ1DFtbl <- xtabs(Amount ~ CandidateType + Step, inExQ1DF)

kable(inExQ1DFtbl, caption = "Q1 2018")
```

However, I get the error code whenever I try to run the almost exactly same code, but with Pct instead of Amount:

```
inExQ1DFtbl <- xtabs(Pct ~ CandidateType + Step, inExQ1DF)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

Does anyone have a quick fix for this, or maybe an alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `data.table` and `tableHTML`:

```
library(data.table)
library(tableHTML)
```

First you transpose your data from long to wide using `dcast()`, then you create an HTML table using `tableHTML`:

```
dcast(inExQ1DF,
      CandidateType ~ Step,
      value.var = "Pct") %>% 
  tableHTML(rownames = FALSE,
            caption = "Q1 2018",
            theme = 'scientific')
```

The result is this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer! One question: Does this work if I want to do a PDF markdown as well?

Comment: Yes, you can use it in RMarkdown.